# Complex coefficient plot in R

Tags: r, plot, coefficients

I am trying to create a coefficient plot for regression results from two survey experiments. Both survey experiments asked the same questions (variables are identical) in two different countries. I am then running 2x2 models with only the treatment (independent variable with 3 levels) and control variables remaining constant.

Here is sample code with robust standard errors:

```
library(estimatr)
set.seed(124)
dv1 <- sample(0:1, 25, replace = TRUE)
dv2 <- sample(0:5, 25, replace = TRUE)

treatment_lvl <- sample(0:3, 25, replace = TRUE)
treatment_lvl <- factor(treatment_lvl, labels = c("baseline", "treatment1", "treatment2", "treatment3"))

control1 <- sample(2:10, 25, replace = TRUE)
control2 <- sample(0:3, 25, replace = TRUE)

df_country1 <- data.frame(dv1, dv2, treatment_lvl, control1, control2)

set.seed(200)
dv1 <- sample(0:1, 25, replace = TRUE)
dv2 <- sample(0:5, 25, replace = TRUE)

treatment_lvl <- sample(0:3, 25, replace = TRUE)
treatment_lvl <- factor(treatment_lvl, labels = c("baseline", "treatment1", "treatment2", "treatment3"))

control1 <- sample(2:10, 25, replace = TRUE)
control2 <- sample(0:3, 25, replace = TRUE)

df_country2 <- data.frame(dv1, dv2, treatment_lvl, control1, control2)

model1 <- lm(dv1 ~ treatment_lvl + control1 + control2, data=df_country1)
model2 <- lm(dv1 ~ treatment_lvl + control1 + control2, data=df_country2)
model3 <- lm(dv2 ~ treatment_lvl + control1 + control2, data=df_country1)
model4 <- lm(dv2 ~ treatment_lvl + control1 + control2, data=df_country2)


model1_robust <- commarobust(model1, se_type = "stata")
model2_robust <- commarobust(model2, se_type = "stata")
model3_robust <- commarobust(model3, se_type = "stata")
model4_robust <- commarobust(model4, se_type = "stata")
```

I now want to visualize the regressions (model1-4) in the following way:

- y-axis: Dependent variable 1, dependent variable 2
- Three plots/facets next to each other: One per treatment level (1-3)
- For each dependent variable and treatment level one coefficient plot for country1 and one for country 2, stacked above each other
- Control variables should not be shown

Something similar to the picture below, but with two instead of three countries. Then on the y-axis it would show the dependent variable of model 1+2; and at the second tick the dv of model 3+4. The other ticks would not be necessary. Instead of "Average treatment effect" it would be "Treatment 1" and then next to it the same for "Treatment 2" and "Treatment 3".
[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want your plot to look like, e.g., a similar-looking plot from a journal article? Coefficient plots usually have at least one continuous axis, but it sounds like you want your x-axis (3 levels) and y-axis (2 levels) to both be discrete.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I included a picture with descriptions. I also edited my question. It actually makes little sense to have everything on one x-axis. One plot per treatment makes more sense and then put them next to each other for comparability